# Why my Visual Studio failed to find definition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to read some code(those code depends some unavailable lib so I'm not able to compile them, luckily I only need to read them) and using VS community 2017 15.7.5. I download the whole thing from github and use File->Open->Folder to import the whole folder. I found that when I try to find definition of a function(using F12), VS always jump to the declaration in the head file, even the .h file and the .cc containing the definition are in the same folder. What can I do to solve this problem?

Here's a simple demo:

main.cc:

```
#include "test.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo();
}
```

test.h

```
void foo();
```

test.cc

```
void foo(){}
```

putting everything in one folder and open using operation above, no matter I use F12 or Ctrl+F12, VS only open test.h but not test.cc.

Comment: Please specify what code are you trying to work with. A concrete example would also be helpful.

Comment: @pablo285 thanks very much for comments, I've add a simple example which might be helpful clarifying my problem.

Comment: Is this in VS project or cmake project?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk sorry my knowledge of C++ and VS is quite limited, I guess I'm even not making it a project. I just use the File->Open->Folder(like https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/04/04122016-BUILD-OpenFolder-OpenFromWindowsExplorerOrFileMenu.png) and VS will open the folder as it is.

Comment: Which github project? Where in the project? Please specify with details, what You do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `F12`, try `ctrl` + `F12`. LINK: [Default Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx#bkmk_edit)

Comment: thanks very much, I've tried both and they always open the header file.